# Passing a struct by reference without passing as a *structobject in the function parameters

Tags: go, pointers

I need to pass a struct as a reference to a function; however, I cannot use pointer (`*`) syntax in my function parameters:

```
func abc(client cleintpassedasrefernce) {
    // make changes in client so that it will be updated in the client actual memory location
}


type clienttobepassasref struct {
    data int
    name string
} 

// calling abc function 
object = clienttobepassasref{}
abc(object)
```

Maybe I can create another struct like type object passed struct

```
{
    object *clienttobepassasref
}
```

and pass this object and access it later in the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change both the function signature, and the method by which you're calling the function. Also you're defining a struct type called `clienttobepassasref` but your function is accepting a struct type of `cleintpassedasrefernce` which is not defined in your example. I replaced these with a struct type in my example called `MyObject`.

[go playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/RWOS7r11p9Z)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyObject struct {
    data int
    name string
}

// accept a pointer to the object here using the '*' character
func abc(obj *MyObject) {
    // make changes in client so that it will be updated in the client actual memory location
    obj.name = "foo"
}

func main() {
    // calling abc function
    object := MyObject{}
    abc(&object)
    // Pass it by reference here with the '&' character
    fmt.Println(object.name)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick revert, as i mentioned i have weird situation , where i can not pass the ampersand as below 

abc(&object) 

and can not  put a asterik in the function params section.
as 
func abc(obj *MyObject)

as my framework is relying on the prevalidate, run , steps where i can define the function name and the params it can take , now due to passing my reference there will be a huge rework. so thinking if somehow i can pass the memory address of the object and take it without above & and * , may be by putting the object to be passed in a wrapper

Comment: @vm-power can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm not sure how you plan on passing a reference to an object without passing a reference to an object. Go ahead and try the wrapper approach, without an example of what you're trying to do, there's not much I can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update, change struct's properties, then create a function (method) with receiver of that struct reference and update struct's properties in that function (method).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyObject struct {
    data int
    name string
}

func (obj *MyObject)abc() {
    // make changes in client so that it will be updated in the client actual memory location
    obj.name = `some name`
    obj.data = 10
}

func main() {
    // calling abc function
    object := &MyObject{}
    object.abc()

    fmt.Printf("object = %+v", *object)
    //object = {data:10 name:some name}
}
```

run the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Fj8-B3hSexC)

reference to get some more knowledge

- [tour.golang.org](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4)
- [go-method-receiver-pointer-vs-value](https://medium.com/globant/go-method-receiver-pointer-vs-value-ffc5ab7acdb)